# add our country's holidays in the open ERP 7 calendar

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, erp

I need a little help around the calendar. I want to add our country's holidays in the ERP calendar. The calendar from the ERP ( Sales->Meetings) allows only to add request of leaves/vacations for employees and to add meetings to a chosen date.
Is there any extension module to the holiday module or another one to be able to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is already there to resolve your problem.

The author of the apps is "credativ". The following [link](http://v6apps.openerp.com/addon/8168?filter=%7B%22text_search%22%3a%20%22public_holidays%22,%20%22order_by%22%3a%20%22click_counter%20desc%22,%20%22author%22%3a%20null%7D&page=0) may help you to find the solution.

Through this module you can define the annual holidays and also weekends holidays country wise.

Hope it will help you in better way and only need few modification in code is required else everything is going right.

Also this module is for version 6.1 so you need to migrate this module in version 7. At the initial level you can check the functionality of above one link module in OpenERP version 6.1.

Comment: I tried that...it installs without error on openerp 7 but it gives error in .xml file. Error is as follows:                                        <xpath expr="//notebook/page/field[@name = 'date_from']" position="replace">   we all know that this module is inherited from hr_holidays but still giving error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to migrate that module, there is already a module for v7: https://www.openerp.com/apps/7.0/hr_public_holidays/